# excluding a set of observations in subsetting

Tags: r, subset

Suppose I have a data on characteristics of organisms. I want to subset the data on the basis of species. I have under species 50 types of species and I want to subset by excluding one species for example amphibians. What command can help me do that ?
One way to do it is by writing explicitly the names of all the species explicitly in the subset command as follows

```
sub <- subset(data, species %in% c("species1,species2,...,species50))  #all species excluding amplhibians.
```

But this will be a very hectic process. How can I use the subset command to get my result ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: just negate the test:

```
sub <- subset(data, ! species %in% 'amphibians')
```

Or, since you only want to exclude one species:

```
sub <- subset(data, species != 'amphibians')
```

Note that prefix-`!` has a different operator precedence in R than in other languages: in almost all other programming languages, the first piece of code would require parentheses around the `species %in% 'amphibians'` test. In R, this isn’t necessary: `! a %in% b` is equivalent to `! (a %in% b)`.

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(138)`

Comment: @RHertel Agreed. However, I *am* sure. And redundant parentheses don’t add clarity, they add clutter. — And there’s no real ambiguity here.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I was using the same method but doing a silly mistake by adding ! before amphibians rather than species. I'm new to R so I do this silly errors a lot of times. Thank you so much though!